# Why does my libcurl c program fail on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, curl, libcurl

I have performed the following steps to download libcurl:

1. Download libcurl from https://curl.se/windows/ (32-bit version)
2. Extract the folder to %USERPROFILE%\Downloads (renamed it to "curl")

I have written the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Running...");
    CURLcode code = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    printf("%d\n", code);
    if (code != 0)
        return 1;
    char *version = curl_version();
    printf("%s", version);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it using MinGW (32 bit) gcc:

```
gcc libcurl_test.c -o libcurl_test.exe -I %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\curl\include -L %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\curl\lib -lcurl

echo %errorlevel%
0
```

When I try to run the program, this happens:

```
.\libcurl_test.exe

echo %errorlevel%
-1073741515
```

I expected this:

```
.\libcurl_test.exe
Running...0
Done

echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Which is what happens when I don't call the curl functions:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Running...");
    // CURLcode code = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    // printf("%d\n", code);
    // if (code != 0)
    //     return 1;
    // char *version = curl_version();
    // printf("%s", version);
    // curl_global_cleanup();
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc libcurl_test.c -o libcurl_test.exe -I C:\Users\Caleb\Downloads\curl\include -L C:\Users\Caleb\Downloads\curl\lib -lcurl

echo %errorlevel%
0

.\libcurl_test.exe
Running...Done

echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: For one, you're not checking whether [`curl_global_init` succeeds](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html), so all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Checked that, and still fails. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Aside: `printf(version);` is dangerous. What if `version` contains a `%`? Safer to do `printf("%s", version)`.

Comment: So helpful mate, thank you so much. Thanks for making my totally nonfunctional code a bit safer, bloody legend mate.

Comment: -1073741515 = 0xC0000135 = STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND. The curl dll needs to be somewhere the exe will find it. Either in %PATH% or in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

> -1073741515 = 0xC0000135 = STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND. The curl dll needs to be somewhere the exe will find it. Either in %PATH% or in same directory. – Luke

It seems that, along with the static libraries, curl also needs the .dll to be present to work. Thanks Luke!

Comment: You don't link with a static library, you link with dll export library.